# Open another view which is out of navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have following in the Storyboard.

```
0 TabBarController
1    |-> NavBarController1
2        |-> ProductsTableViewController
3            |-> ModallyPresentedOrderProductViewController
4    |-> NavBarController2
5        |-> OrdersTableViewController
6            |-> OrderDetailViewController
```

I want to select the product in (2) then order the product in (3) with some options and then after ordering is completed, I want it to **open** the OrderDetail (6) as it will return to Orders to (5) if I click on the back button instead of OrderProduct to (3).

dismissViewControllerAnimated doesn't help since it returns to products (2).
presentViewController doesn't help since it returns back to the OrderProduct view (3).
segue doesn't help since it works similar to dismissViewControllerAnimated.

**I want to show the saved order record in OrderDetail view (6) which is not in the same navigation stack with the presented view.**

Like:
Close the new product order view when "Place Order" button clicked.
Click on the Orders tab bar button at the bottom.
Click on the Order cell in the table view and open the Order Detail view.

Thanks for reading. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Unwind Segue which is the perfect solution for this.